# iPhone app to apply Instagram like filters to a photo and save to camera roll

Tags: iphone, applications, camera

Is there such an iphone app which gives me multiple filters to apply to a photo and save it to photo library camera roll (syncs to iPhoto later).

It appears the photos are stored inside the Instagram app only when they get uploaded to the Instragram servers.

I read the description of Hipstamatic on iTunes but I'm hesitant to buy it as it doesn't seem to have the option I want.

Better yet, is there someway to save the instagram photos to photo library apart from mailing them one by one. (Too many questions I know)

Comment: Instagram for me saves to the Camera Roll, the original and the processed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Settings` > `Instagram` you can specify that you want to save the original picture and the picture modified in the photo library.

If you don't want to upload your files in Instagram's server, try [**Camera+**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id329670577?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4). It's a great app and really worth the 99 cents.

NB: there's also a free **Camera Plus** app, it's not the same as **Camera+** and I haven't tried it.

Comment: +1 for Camera+, as well as how my Instagram is setup to do this.

Comment: +1 for Camera+. And dont miss that they offer a great analog filter pack.

Comment: +1 Yeah! Camera+ is exactly what I needed. Although Instagram can also save to photo library, but it also uploads on instagram servers (doesn't bode well when there is no signal in metro trains)

Comment: Another vote for Camera+ - the way you can take lots of pictures in quick succession and then later upload them all to the 'camera roll' makes it much more usable than the built-in camera app.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution](http://jaxov.com/2011/04/apply-instagram-filters-to-iphone-photos-without-posting-them-to-feed/) which actually works.

(Basically, the solution is to not take the picture with Instagram, but to open the picture from the camera roll and filter/crop it from there, and it should automatically save back.)

Comment: Can you describe the solution at the link? Something like that (a personal blog) is very susceptible to link rot.